# jenkins plugin not getting installed

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Each time after installing the pipeline plugin and restarting the plugin vanished from installed list a am getting the below error.

I am using the Jenkins version `2.28`

```
There are dependency errors loading some plugins:
Pipeline: Milestone Step v1.3.1
Pipeline: API v2.11 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
GitHub Branch Source Plugin v2.3.2
GitHub plugin v1.26.0 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Jenkins SSH plugin v2.6.1
Jenkins JSch dependency plugin v0.1.54.1 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Pipeline: GitHub Groovy Libraries v1.0
Pipeline: Shared Groovy Libraries v2.5 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Pipeline: Multibranch v2.21
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.121.1 or later to run this plugin.
Pipeline: API v2.27 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Docker Pipeline v1.23
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.150.3 or later to run this plugin.
Pipeline: Basic Steps v2.18 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Maven Integration plugin v3.6
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.60.3 or later to run this plugin.
Jenkins Apache HttpComponents Client 4.x API Plugin v4.5.5-2.1 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
LDAP Plugin v1.18
Jenkins Mailer Plugin v1.20 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Pipeline: Stage Tags Metadata v1.6.0
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.150.3 or later to run this plugin.
Pipeline: API v2.36 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Jenkins Git client plugin v3.2.1
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.138.4 or later to run this plugin.
Jenkins Apache HttpComponents Client 4.x API Plugin v4.5.10-2.0 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
SCM API Plugin v2.6.3
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.107.3 or later to run this plugin.
Structs Plugin v1.9 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Pipeline: Stage Step v2.3
Pipeline: API v2.15 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Jenkins S3 publisher plugin v0.11.0
Maven Integration plugin v3.1 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Pipeline: Declarative Extension Points API v1.6.0
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.150.3 or later to run this plugin.
Pipeline: Groovy v2.76 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Email Extension Plugin v2.61
JUnit Plugin v1.2 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
GitHub plugin v1.29.0
Credentials Plugin v2.1.8 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Build Timeout v1.19
Token Macro Plugin v1.5.1 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Jenkins Parameterized Trigger plugin v2.36
Conditional BuildStep v1.3.1 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Pipeline: Shared Groovy Libraries v2.16
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.138.4 or later to run this plugin.
Pipeline: API v2.33 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Pipeline: Supporting APIs v3.4
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.138.4 or later to run this plugin.
Pipeline: API v2.36 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Jenkins Mailer Plugin v1.32
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.150.1 or later to run this plugin.
Display URL API v2.3.1 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Jackson 2 API Plugin v2.11.0
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.164.3 or later to run this plugin.
Pipeline: REST API Plugin v2.13
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.60.3 or later to run this plugin.
Pipeline: API v2.24 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Conditional BuildStep v1.3.6
Maven Integration plugin v2.13 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Pipeline: SCM Step v2.11
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.60 or later to run this plugin.
Pipeline: Step API v2.9 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Jenkins Workspace Cleanup Plugin v0.34
Pipeline: Nodes and Processes v2.4 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Pipeline: Model API v1.6.0
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.150.3 or later to run this plugin.
Pipeline: Step API v2.22 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Build Pipeline Plugin v1.5.8
Jenkins Parameterized Trigger plugin v2.17 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Token Macro Plugin v2.12
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.121.3 or later to run this plugin.
Pipeline: Step API v2.14 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Jenkins Multijob plugin v1.29
Maven Integration plugin v2.6 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Amazon Web Services SDK v1.11.264
Jenkins Apache HttpComponents Client 4.x API Plugin v4.5.3-2.0 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Run Condition Plugin v1.3
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.138.4 or later to run this plugin.
Token Macro Plugin v2.12 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Lockable Resources plugin v2.8
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.138.4 or later to run this plugin.
Pipeline: Supporting APIs v3.4 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Pipeline: Input Step v2.11
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.138.4 or later to run this plugin.
Pipeline: API v2.35 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Jenkins GIT server Plugin v1.9
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.138.4 or later to run this plugin.
Jenkins Git client plugin v2.7.6 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Credentials Binding Plugin v1.22
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.164.3 or later to run this plugin.
Pipeline: Step API v2.22 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Pipeline v2.6
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.130 or later to run this plugin.
Lockable Resources plugin v2.3 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Pipeline: Build Step v2.12
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.138.4 or later to run this plugin.
Pipeline: API v2.33 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Pipeline: Stage View Plugin v2.13
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.60.3 or later to run this plugin.
Pipeline: REST API Plugin v2.13 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
HPE Application Automation Tools v5.2
Pipeline: Groovy v2.6 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Credentials Plugin v2.3.7
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.138.4 or later to run this plugin.
Structs Plugin v1.20 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Pipeline: Declarative v1.6.0
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.150.3 or later to run this plugin.
Pipeline: API v2.36 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Config File Provider Plugin v3.6.3
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.121.3 or later to run this plugin.
Credentials Plugin v2.1.4 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Pipeline: Step API v2.22
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.138.4 or later to run this plugin.
Structs Plugin v1.20 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Plain Credentials Plugin v1.7
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.138.4 or later to run this plugin.
Credentials Plugin v2.2.0 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Matrix Project Plugin v1.14
JUnit Plugin v1.20 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Docker Commons Plugin v1.16
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.150.1 or later to run this plugin.
Authentication Tokens API Plugin v1.3 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Jenkins Git plugin v3.7.0
Pipeline: SCM Step v1.14.2 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Authentication Tokens API Plugin v1.3
Credentials Plugin v1.22 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Pipeline: Nodes and Processes v2.31
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.150.1 or later to run this plugin.
Pipeline: API v2.33 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
SSH Credentials Plugin v1.17.4
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.138.4 or later to run this plugin.
Credentials Plugin v2.2.0 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Folders Plugin v6.12
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.138.4 or later to run this plugin.
Jenkins Job Configuration History Plugin v2.26
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.164 or later to run this plugin.
Durable Task Plugin v1.34
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.150.1 or later to run this plugin.
Pipeline: Job v2.39
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.138.4 or later to run this plugin.
Pipeline: API v2.36 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Pipeline: Basic Steps v2.20
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.164.3 or later to run this plugin.
Pipeline: API v2.40 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Jenkins JSch dependency plugin v0.1.55.1
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.60.3 or later to run this plugin.
SSH Credentials Plugin v1.14 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Copy Artifact Plugin v1.39
Matrix Project Plugin v1.3 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
GitHub API Plugin v1.90
Jackson 2 API Plugin v2.7.3 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
JUnit Plugin v1.29
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.164.3 or later to run this plugin.
Pipeline: API v2.40 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Pipeline Graph Analysis Plugin v1.10
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.138.4 or later to run this plugin.
Pipeline: API v2.34 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Structs Plugin v1.20
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.107.3 or later to run this plugin.
Jenkins Apache HttpComponents Client 4.x API Plugin v4.5.10-2.0
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.60.3 or later to run this plugin.
Ant Plugin v1.8
Structs Plugin v1.6 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Pipeline: Groovy v2.80
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.138.4 or later to run this plugin.
Pipeline: API v2.36 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Jenkins SSH Slaves plugin v1.25
Credentials Plugin v2.1.2 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
GitHub Organization Folder Plugin v1.6
Folders Plugin v5.16 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Gradle Plugin v1.28
Structs Plugin v1.3 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Environment Injector Plugin v2.1.5
Matrix Project Plugin v1.7 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Jenkins Subversion Plug-in v2.10.2
Pipeline: SCM Step v1.14.2 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Display URL API v2.3.2
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.89.4 or later to run this plugin.
Script Security Plugin v1.71
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.60.3 or later to run this plugin.
Pipeline: Declarative Agent API v1.1.1
Pipeline: Declarative Extension Points API v1.1.1 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Node and Label parameter plugin v1.7.2
Token Macro Plugin v1.11 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Branch API Plugin v2.5.6
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.138.4 or later to run this plugin.
Folders Plugin v6.11 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Pipeline: API v2.40
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.150.3 or later to run this plugin.
Pipeline: Step API v2.16 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
Pipeline: Multibranch with defaults v2.1
You must update Jenkins from v2.28 to v2.130 or later to run this plugin.
Pipeline: API v2.29 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
```